# Отступы для текста

Tags: html, css

Я могу задать отступы (margin) для текста? Ну, что чтобы у текста был отступ сверху и снизу...

Comment: лучше уж padding

Comment: А использовать margin - это считается ошибкой?

Comment: при помощи [`margin`](https://webref.ru/css/margin) можно задавать  внешние отступы, т.е. элемент отталкивается от родительского/соседнего элемента, [`padding`](https://webref.ru/css/padding) же устанавливает внутренние отступы, т.е. для родителя останавливаем внутренние отступы и все.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: А вот такой вопрос, а для селектора p можно устанавливать class ?

Comment: На всё можно..:)

Comment: я никаких запретов по этому поводу не знаю, и даже больше, проходил 1 курс по [верстке](https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/htmlcss) и сам делал именно так, курс прошел, защитился успешно

Comment: То есть, задавать class для текстов это нормально? То есть, не является ошибкой в верстке?

Comment: нет, ошибкой это не является, попробуйте по проходить курсы по приведенной мной ссылке, там есть бесплатные, многие вопросы в результате прохождения отпадут(у меня было именно так, правда потом могут появиться новые, но это же хорошо)

Comment: а где ссылка на курс?

Comment: *проходил 1 курс по **верстке*** это ссылка на интенсив, если перейти по ней то там есть курсы, на всякий случай продублирую: [htmlacademy.ru](https://htmlacademy.ru/courses)

Comment: ok, спасибо большое!